# Puedo poner estilos en el csv que creo con csvView cakephp

Tags: csv, cakephp, plugin, style

Este es el csv que genero. Con el plugin de cakephp CsvView

```
public function export(){

    $this->loadModel('PedidosVentas');
    $condiciones = array('fecha BETWEEN "2020-01-01" and "2020-01-31"'=> array('2020-01-01','2020-01-31'));


    $pedidos = $this->PedidosVentas->find("all",array('conditions'=>array('fecha BETWEEN "2020-01-01" and "2020-01-31"')))->select(['cliente_id','usuario','centro_id','tipo_articulo_id'])->distinct('centro_id');
    $this->loadModel('Centros');
    $centro = $this->Centros->find()->select(['id','poblacion','nombre','codigio_gerencia'])->where(['tipo_centro_id' => '2'])->all();

    $this->loadModel('TipoArticulos');
    $articulos = $this->TipoArticulos->find('all')->select(['id','nombre'])->toArray();

    $dias = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN , '01' , '2020');

    $arrayTotal = [];
    foreach ($centro as $c) 
    {
        foreach ($articulos as $articulo)
        {
            $array['ID'] = $c->id;
            $array['Gerencia'] = $c->poblacion;
            $array['Centro'] = $c->nombre;
            $array['ID_gerencia'] = $c->codigio_gerencia;
            $array['articulo'] = $articulo->nombre;
            for($i=1; $i<=$dias ; $i++)
            {
                $array[$i] = $this->PedidosVentas->find()->where(['fecha' => '2020-01-'.$i , 'centro_id' => $c->id])->count();
                if(isset($arrayT[$i]) == false){
                    $arrayT[$i] = 0;
                }
                $arrayT[$i] = $arrayT[$i] + $array[$i];
            }
            array_push($arrayTotal,$array);
        }

        $array['ID'] = "";
        $array['Gerencia'] = "";
        $array['Centro'] = "";
        $array['ID_gerencia'] = "";
        $array['articulo'] = "Total Articulos";
        for($i=1; $i<=$dias ; $i++)
            {
                $array[$i] =  $arrayT[$i];
            }
        array_push($arrayTotal,$array);
        $arrayT=[];
    }

    $_serialize = 'arrayTotal';
    $_header = ['ID', 'Gerencia', 'Centro','ID_gerencia','articulo'];


    $dias = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN , '01' , '2020');
    for ($i=1; $i<=$dias ; $i++){
        array_push($_header,$i);
    }

    $this->response = $this->response->withDownload('Pedidos.csv');
    $this->viewBuilder()->setClassName('CsvView.Csv');
    $this->set(compact('arrayTotal', '_serialize','_header'));
}
```

Y me gustaria saber si hay alguna manera de ponerle estilos a mis titulos, no encuentro información.

Answer (score 0):

En un fichero CSV los datos se guardan en crudo, separados por comas y saltos de línea. No hay una sintaxis específica para definir estilos ni ningún otro tipo de cambios en la presentación del documento (saltos de página, cabeceras, etc).

Para hacer este tipo de documentos con estilos, tendrás que generarlo en algún formato de hoja de cálculo (XLS, XLSX, ODS, etc.)

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180